# Show count for only specific values

Tags: php, mysql, database, count

I'm not understanding where I'm going wrong with this. I want the counter to only show when the payment status (column in database is payment_status) shows FREE or COMPLETED, and if columns Name, Song, and Band have something filled in (not blank). Below is the code I have, however it's counting the entries even if the payment_status is null. Any help is appreciated.

What I did do:
Besides searching everywhere I can find, I tried to take out, rearrange, and change the different values in each of the lines for Empty and NULLIF parts.

Here is my code

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT id, name, band, song, extra, band2, song2, extra2, band3, 
                song3, extra3, item_name, payment_status 
        FROM nametable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


$resultt = mysqli_query($conn, "select COUNT(  NULLIF( song, '' ) ) +
                                       COUNT(  NULLIF( song2, '' ) ) + 
                                       COUNT(  NULLIF( song3, '' ) ) AS count 
                                FROM `nametable` ");

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if( $row['payment_status'] == "Completed" || 
            $row['payment_status'] == "Free")
        {
        
            if( !empty($row["name"]) && 
                !empty($row["band"]) && 
                !empty($row["song"])  )
            {

                if(!$result) {
                    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
                } else {
                    $num_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultt);
                    // echo it
                    echo "<font color='aqua'>" . $num_rows['count']."</font>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo " ";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Oh okay thank you so much for the heads up on that. I appreciate it

Comment: `WHERE payment_status IN('FREE', 'COMPLETED') AND name is not NULL and name != '' etc etc`

Comment: @RiggsFolly AHHHHH thank you so much. That did the trick. I appreciate you!

Answer (score 0):

You could obtain the result directly form db

```
select COUNT(  NULLIF( song, '' ) ) +
       COUNT(  NULLIF( song2, '' ) ) + 
       COUNT(  NULLIF( song3, '' ) ) AS count 
       FROM `nametable`
       WHERE payment_status IN ('FREE ', 'COMPLETED')
       AND concat(ifnull(Name,''), ifnull(Song,''), ifnull(Band ,'')) != ''
```

Comment: How could that be altered so that only the NULL entries are counted?

Comment: I have the following..... $resultt = mysqli_query($conn, "select count(ifnull(payment_status,' ')) AS count FROM `nametable` WHERE payment_status IS NULL");